# Confused with a sentence mixing conjunctions without commas

Tags: ambiguity, conjunctions

These are the exclusions wording of my home insurance policy:

> LPG fuelled, oil fired, warm air, solar **and** unvented heating systems **or** boilers with an output over 60Kw/hr

I have an “*unvented heating system with an output of 40Kw/hr*” and need to know whether it is covered or not.

The fact that the sentence contains an enumeration of items with commas could imply that the “and” is preceding the last item in the list “*unvented heating systems **or** boilers **both** with an output over 60Kw/hr*” meaning it **IS NOT EXCLUDED** however the “or” could also imply it is preceding the last item in the list “*boilers with an output over 60Kw/hr*” so the previous item would become “*solar **and all kinds of** unvented heating systems*” meaning it **IS EXCLUDED**.

Are there any specific rules in the English Grammar that can be applied to this kind of ambiguous sentences to resolve the ambiguity with 100% of certainty?

Comment: Couldn't you just ask your insurance company? Their answer would be far more authoritative than any you could get here.

Comment: Law SE is a better place to ask about legal language; normal English grammar does not always apply, and there are often rules for handling ambiguity.

Comment: I'd read this as << Boilers with an output over 60Kw/hr and other  heating systems with an output over 60Kw/hr, whether LPG fuelled, oil fired, warm air, solar, or unvented >> But (1) don't take this as authoritative, and (2) I don't see how 'vented' matches the other descriptors which list fuel types/energy sources. //// I'd certainly seek clarification. This screed violates Grice's maxim of manner (clarity).

Comment: I'd agree with other commenters that this is a question for a lawyer rather than a linguist.  See [O’Connor v. Oakhurst Dairy](https://www.loweringthebar.net/2017/03/the-oxford-comma-use-it.html) for a case where this precise ambiguity had serious financial consequences.

Comment: I would not enquire too deeply into the exclusions: at the moment, the ambiguity goes in your favour as a reasonable interpretation is that your boiler is not in the exclusions as it is under 60KwH. I refer you to the case of Oakhurt Dairy.(https://www.theguardian.com/books/2017/mar/16/oxford-comma-helps-drivers-win-dispute-about-overtime-pay)

Comment: If excluding certain boilers/heaters, I'm not going to give you a choice (or), but collect all those disallowed (and). If you're not sure if it's excluded, my lawyers already figured that out: it's excluded. Big heaters are unprotected by this coverage. Language unclear to you is not a negative to the insurer.

Comment: Thanks for your replies! If I need to take the matter to court then, of course, I'll check with a lawyer first, however at this point I'm only interested in the English Grammar rules that could help me resolve the ambiguity without a possible doubt.  I've been searching for all kinds of conjunction rules and examples but I haven't been able to find any related to the mix of "and" with "or", precedences, etc.

Comment: Thanks, @YosefBaskin, however my heater is not big, it's fairly standard so, from that point of view, it should be included.

Comment: Yes, your heater is under the big limit. The firm inspected your home and gave you coverage. Home scale, not commercial scale.

Comment: Thanks, @YosefBaskin; however at this point I'm not interested in common sense or the actual domain concepts; I'm looking for English Grammar rules dealing with conjunction precedence, etc.

Answer (score 1):

In English grammar, this is known as syntactic or structural ambiguity. It occurs when a sentence or sequence of words has two or more possible meanings.

In your case, the ambiguity arises from the use of the conjunctions “and” and “or”, and the lack of clear punctuation to separate the items in the list. The intended meaning of a syntactically ambiguous phrase can generally—although not always—be determined by the context of its use. However, in this case, the context does not provide enough information to resolve the ambiguity with 100% certainty.